# Connection to url unauthorized

Tags: android, connection, http-get

Itry to create a connection to an URL to check the last content modification, with the created username/password as basic authentication. The returned modification time should be checked with the last modification time and stored for reference. If the modification time is newer (higher) the rest of the content should be downloaded.

I am getting an autorization problem when i try to establish connection.

Here is what i do:

My login and pwd:

```
String username = "haythem";
String key ="FU2ra88xuhuf6-#At+aseQub8f8ebr$sweh$thu!Ep?*frusAvEdRamuw9thubr";
String password = AeSimpleSHA1.SHA1(key + username);
```

My SHA1 code:

```
public static String SHA1(String text) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, UnsupportedEncodingException {
        MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");
        md.update(text.getBytes("UTF-8"), 0, text.length());
        byte[] sha1hash = md.digest();
        return convertToHex(sha1hash);
    }
```

My web service code:

```
String mUrl = "http://app-vantage.appspot.com/api4/modified";
HttpGet request = new HttpGet(mUrl);
HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
params.setParameter("Authorization",  "Basic " + android.util.Base64.encodeToString((username + ":" + password).getBytes(), android.util.Base64.DEFAULT));
params.setParameter("User-Agent", "SDKDemo/1.0");
request.setParams(params);
```

Now i am getting 401 error.

status =401

```
<html><head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
<title>401 UNAUTHORIZED</title>
/head>
<body text=#000000 bgcolor=#ffffff>
<h1>Error: UNAUTHORIZED</h1>
</body></html>
```

I don't know what is going wrong with web services ...

Here is the documentation, i got:

Authentication
Phases 1 is required to go over HTTPS with Basic authentication. The Basic authentication used is a generated username (generate a type 4 UUID) and as password the application key plus the username as UTF-8 hashed with SHA-1 sent as hex. For instance with an application key of "abcd" and a surename of 1111-2222 the data is:

username: 1111-2222
password: SHA1(abcd1111-2222) = 970e1294ff2abd10d037ec73988646584bd8840e

thus:
Authentication: Basic MTExMS0yMjIyOjk3MGUxMjk0ZmYyYWJkMTBkMDM3ZWM3Mzk4ODY0NjU4NGJkODg0MGU=

Answer (score 5):

There are a few things which immediately jump out:

1. You are trying to access the URL **http:**//app-vantage.appspot.com/api4/modified, yet per your description, you are required to use **https:**.
2. Your description says "generated username (generate a type 4 UUID)" (this means random). Your username ("haythem"), however, does not appear to be particularly random.

   In addition, you should verify the following:
3. Verify that your `convertToHex()` function is returning the same case as the server-side is expecting. If you are generating a hex in capital letters and they are expecting lower-case letters, it can sometimes cause an error.
4. If you happen to have access to the server-side, try looking at the logs to see what is going on.